# Как установить Ratchet и как его задействовать?

Tags: ratchet

Я открыл документацию на socketo.me. Куда-то кликнул-кликнул, и как-то появилась папка cboden\ratchet. Ок.

Дальше смотрю:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
```

Это что такое? Что за psr-0? Что за непонятные названия дают? К чему относится src?

```
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
```

Этот код красным подсвечивается. Я не понимаю, откуда это он должен брать.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

И это что такое? Что за autoload? Что за vendor?

Как с этим работать? Объясните кто-нибудь на пальцах.

Comment: getcomposer.org

Comment: Он уже установлен

Comment: там вся документация и по vendor/autoload, и по psr-0